# How to suggest an edit to a blog post?

Tags: support, blog

In [QoTW #51](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2014/12/qotw-51-would-it-be-good-secure-programming-practice-to-overwrite-a-sensitive-variable-before-deleting-it/?cb=1)

> Lotenfogle points out...

The only option I saw was to leave a comment, which is more permanent than suggesting an edit feature we have on questions/answers.

Comment: Is the change you want just the name correction? If so, that is complete now.

Answer (score 2):

With the blog, commenting is pretty much the only option you have, yes, but you shouldn't think of comments as being more permanent. In reality comments on SE are very much temporary, and edits are the way to make changes.

Once the comment has been acted on, we can easily delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange posts aim at being the definite knowledge database for a specific topic, so they can be edited in case they're almost, but not quite right. Blog posts are rather more personal: they're the author's piece, so they aren't editable by just anyone.

A few people have the privilege to edit blog posts. (I don't have the list of users and their privileges.) If you want a blog post to be edited, you can reach the editors in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) (if you don't know who to ping, ping [a site moderator](https://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)) or here on meta.